# Set of functions in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

Let $X$ uncountable. Show that set of injective functions $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have empty interior in B(X;R),where $B(X;\mathbb{R})$ is set of limited fucntions.

Comment: If $f$ is injective, what do you know about the set $f(X)$?

Comment: If f is injective i know that f(X) is uncountable

Comment: what is  $X$   ? A metric space ?

Comment: you have to endow the set of functions with a topology before considering interiors

Comment: Right. And what do you know about uncountable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I did not understand, we know exactly about uncountable subsets of R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that such the image of such a function $f$ must have an accumulation point in ${\Bbb R}$. Show then that arbitrarily close to $f$ (for the uniform distance) there is a non-injective map.

A few more details:

Let $d(f,\tilde{f}) = \sup |f(u)-\tilde{f}(u)|$ be the uniform distance between $f,\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow {\Bbb R}$ (possibly taking the value $+\infty$ if we permit unbounded functions).

If $X$ is uncountable and $f$ injective show that (use that rationals are countable and dense in ${\Bbb R}$) there is $y\in {\Bbb R}$ which is an accumulation point of  $f(X)$. For $\epsilon>0$ there are $x_0,x_1$ so that $|y-f(x_0)|,|y-f(x_1)|<\epsilon$. Define now:
$\tilde{f}(x)=y$ if $x=x_0$ or $x=x_1$ and $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)$ otherwise. Then $d(f,\tilde{f})<\epsilon$ but $\tilde{f}$ is not injective.

If you only consider bounded functions then it suffices that $X$ is not finite for this argument to work, since a countable bounded sequence has an accumulation point.

Comment: I know I must show that a ball of radius epsilon around a function f must be a non-injective function, but I have no idea how to show it.

Comment: Show first that if $f$ does not have an accumulation point in ${\Bbb R}$ then $f(X)$ must be countable which was excluded. Now if $y$ is an accumulation point and $\epsilon>0$ then there are $x,x'\in X$ so that $f(x)$,$f(x')$ are $\epsilon/2$ close to $y$. You may then make an $\epsilon$ change of $f$ at say $x$ so that the the function is no longer injective.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I still can not relate to the fact that X is not countable with this set have empty interior.

Comment: I still can not see exactly how to show that a ball of this set will have at least one function that is not injective.